# How to Re install Android 4.2.2 on Samsung galaxy grand

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, odin, downgrade, samsung-galaxy-grand

I am using *Samsung Galaxy Grand GT-I9082* from past one year. I got lot of software updates and did all of them, including the 4.2.2 JellyBean FirmWare Update.

Recently I got one stability update, after which my mobile lost it's stability. Now I want to revert back to Jelly Bean *prior* to that update, by re-installing 4.2.2 JellyBean FirmWare. I have read few blogs about the procedure with Odin but I am confused whether that procedure only works when my mobile is loaded with 4.1.2, or with any version? Currently I am using 4.2.2 Jelly Bean.

I have tried hard reseting the device and wiping the cache partition; but still the device is slow, constantly hanging sometimes, and I am missing important calls also.

Answer (score 1):

I Have Replaced ROM in my mobile using [Odin](http://www.android.gs/download-odin-3-07/) and downloaded official Jelly Bean Firmware from  [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) and installed by following [instructions](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-tos/300296-guide-samsung-how-flash-stock-rom-via-odin.html)
i was able to succesfully flash the Jelly Bean Released on nov 11 2013 and after flashing i did following

> Wiped User Data (Factory RESET)
>
> Wiped Cache Partition

Now it's working like charm